# How to get button text to align top in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, alignment

I have some text inside a button. I want this text to be aligned at the top of the button. By default it seems to be aligned to the middle. In webkit I can get this text to align top using -webkit-box-align: start; This doesn't seem to work for IE.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/RY6dQ/

Comment: Which version(s) of IE please? IE6 != IE9 ;) Lesser IE: I begin by padding and line-height

Comment: Does it have to be exactly n pixels tall? Or was that just for an example?

Answer (score 1):

You could try following ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/RY6dQ/3/)):

html:

```
<button><span>Text</span></button>​
```

css:

```
button {
     height: 100px;
}

button span{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;

}
```

Comment: That was what I thought of doing, it works great :) (in IE 6, 7, 8 an 9!), great one!

Comment: This is what I am doing at the moment. Can't believe there isn't a property to override this behaviour!