# Top-align text within button element?

Tags: html, css

I have some buttons that have varying numbers of lines of text, all with a fixed width and height. It seems that anything I put between the `<button> </button>` tags are vertically aligned to the middle by default. I want to vertically align the text within the button to the top, so that the first line of each button starts at the same line.

One workaround I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10756422), but as you can see in this example (http://jsfiddle.net/d27NA/1/), with this approach, I have to manually designate the top property for buttons that contain texts of different lengths, else buttons that contain longer text will overflow the top.

I'm wondering if there is an alternate approach that will solve this problem in a more elegant way. Thanks.

html:

```
<div>
    <button class="test">
        This text is vertically center-aligned. I want this to be top-aligned.
    </button>
</div>
```

css:

```
.test{
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:14px;
    text-align:center;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yup, just define the button as `position:relative;` and the span as `position:absolute;top:0;left:0;` and you're in business.

[jsFiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/d27NA/4/)

**UPDATE**

So in the three years since this answer, flexbox has become more prominent. As such, you can do this now:

```
.test {
    display: inline-flex; /* keep the inline nature of buttons */
    align-items: flex-start; /* this is default */
}
```

This should give you what you're looking for. You may need to apply `appearance: none;` (with appropriate browser prefixes), but that should do it.

Comment: This is great. However, it seems that for text that fits in a single line, the text becomes left aligned (as can be seen in the jsfiddle) Is there a way to fix this to make it center aligned?

Comment: yeah sorry for the delayed response. You can either set `right:0;` like you did (which I prefer) or set an explicit width, like `width:100%;`. either way works.

Comment: I feel like there's got to be a better way to do this, but at least this works. Would prefer if I didn't have to set the innards to `position:absolute;`

Comment: There is, as its been nearly 3 years since this answer. I'll update for current standards

Comment: The flexbox answer only works on Chrome, not Firefox. Unfortunately Firefox doesn't allow you to set buttons as flexboxes...

Comment: For me it worked like this: 

    `display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;`

Comment: Upvote for keeping this answer updated after several years!

Answer (score 6):

You just need to change the CSS of **Button** and **Span**. Separate both the CSS and make following changes:

```
button {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute; //<-- Make it absolute
    top: 0px;           //<-- Set the top property accordingly. In this case 0px;    
}
```

Set the position of **span** as **absolute** and set **top** property accordingly

Comment: you didnt include an X property, such as `left:0;`. firefox pukes at that sometimes, just a heads up.

Answer (score 3):

Like PlantTheIdea's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16244925/584670), this one adds a `<span>`, but is simpler and works across browsers.

```html
<div>
    <button class="test">
        <span>
            This text is vertically center-aligned. I want this to be top-aligned.
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

```css
.test > span {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the BUTTON tag with A or DIV, and then style it to look like a button.