# Text on the top not center in the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have button with text on top

Here is code

```css
.settings-button-new {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: solid 4px #d3dbde;
    -webkit-border-radius: 13px;
    -moz-border-radius: 13px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    font: 15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #1c559b;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#fcfcfc 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfcfc', endColorstr='#fcfcfc',GradientType=0 );
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#fcfcfc 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
}

.settings-button-new span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
 <button class="settings-button-new"><span>Home</span></button>
```

It on the top, but not centered as you can see.

I try to use `text-align: center;` but seems it not works.

How can i center it in button?

Thank's for help

Comment: Updated my answer without absolute markup and I also cleaned up styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add below css code for center, if don't need to vertically center then the `top:0 or as your need;` and `transform: translate(-50%, 0);`.

```
.settings-button-new span {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

```css
.settings-button-new {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 14px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: solid 4px #d3dbde;
  -webkit-border-radius: 13px;
  -moz-border-radius: 13px;
  border-radius: 13px;
  font: 15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #1c559b;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfcfc', endColorstr='#fcfcfc', GradientType=0);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
}

.settings-button-new span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<button class="settings-button-new"><span>Home</span></button>
```

Only center.

```
.settings-button-new span {
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          top: 5px;
          left: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, 0);
        }
```

```css
.settings-button-new {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 14px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: solid 4px #d3dbde;
  -webkit-border-radius: 13px;
  -moz-border-radius: 13px;
  border-radius: 13px;
  font: 15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #1c559b;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfcfc', endColorstr='#fcfcfc', GradientType=0);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
}

.settings-button-new span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<button class="settings-button-new"><span>Home</span></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code can help you

```css
.settings-button-new {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: solid 4px #d3dbde;
    -webkit-border-radius: 13px;
    -moz-border-radius: 13px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    font: 15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #1c559b;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#fcfcfc 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfcfc', endColorstr='#fcfcfc',GradientType=0 );
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#fcfcfc 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
}

.settings-button-new span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
 <button class="settings-button-new"><span>Home</span></button>
```

Comment: That's it. Thank's

Answer (score 1):

You can remove vertical aligning text using without absolute positioning: you can use `vertical-align` and pseudoelement for this. [Source answer for this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26164626/1548895).

Also

- You don't need absolute position in this case (and `text-align: center`).
- I would recommend you to delete vendor prefixed properties because they are for very old browsers
- `linear-gradient` will work for `background`, not `background-image` property

Demo:

```css
/* styles to align button's text at the top */
.settings-button-new:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: inherit;
}

/* styles to align button's text at the top */
.settings-button-new span {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Cleaned up button styles */
.settings-button-new {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: solid 4px #d3dbde;
  border-radius: 13px;
  font: 15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #1c559b;
  background: #fff linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
```

```html
<button class="settings-button-new">
  <span>Home</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.settings-button-new span {
margin: 0px;
text-align: center;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

can you change span to div , text-align:center will then work fine

Answer (score 0):

remove the poistion .and simply add `margin:auto`

```css
.settings-button-new {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: solid 4px #d3dbde;
    -webkit-border-radius: 13px;
    -moz-border-radius: 13px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    font: 15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #1c559b;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#fcfcfc 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfcfc', endColorstr='#fcfcfc',GradientType=0 );
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#fcfcfc 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
}

.settings-button-new span {
    margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<button class="settings-button-new"><span>Home</span></button>
```